# Disabling WiFi while airodump-ng is running crashes the session

Tags: networking, unity, wireless, network-manager, aircrack-ng

I'm starting `airodump-ng` from the `aircrack-ng` package (version `1:1.2-0~beta3-4` on 16.04) like this:

- Switch my WiFi device to monitor mode (creates new virtual interface `mon0`):

  ```
  sudo airmon-ng start wlp3s0
  ```
- Start the dumping:

  ```
  sudo airodump-ng mon0
  ```

Now I'm running the Unity desktop and using the default network manager indicator. If I click on that and remove the tick at `Enable Wi-Fi`, my session immediately crashes and I'm thrown to the log-in screen. All running applications were killed.

Additionally, if I suspend the notebook after that and wake up again, I must enter my password twice, as there appears one additional dialogue window asking for my password to unlock or offering to switch the user. After I enter my password, I get to the ordinary lock screen which asks me again.

Is this all a bug in `airodump-ng`, or is there more about it, am I missing a driver, configuration or anything else that could serve as workaround to avoid this in the future? An answer describing how to not allow to disable the WiFi while `airodump-ng` is running would also count as valid workaround.

---

**Update:**

Here is some information about my WiFi adapter:

```
$ iwconfig
wlp3s0    IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=off   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off

$ lspci | grep -i wireless
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 3165 (rev 81)

$ inxi -n
Network:   Card-2: Intel Wireless 3165 driver: iwlwifi
           IF: wlp3s0 state: down mac: 08:d4:xx:xx:xx:xx

$ sudo lshw -c network
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 3165
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0
       version: 81
       serial: 08:d4:0c:b3:0b:19
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.4.0-24-generic firmware=16.242414.0 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
       resources: irq:127 memory:a4000000-a4001fff
```

Also, I tried what happens if I disable the WiFi not using the network indicator but through the terminal:

```
sudo ifconfig wlp3s0 down
sudo ifconfig mon0 down
```

This did not do anything. My session has not crashed, but `airodump-ng` also did not stop capturing packets... Do I need to use a different command to disable WiFi the same way as the network indicator does?

Comment: I would suggest asking the question to the package maintainer.  Even though the package is available through Ubuntu repos, I don't think this site should have to provide any support for it

Comment: @Jeremy31IMHO I think you're following a false belief here about being on/off topic if something is in fact in the official repositories its perfect on topic here, but I agree with you that a mail to the package maintainers or bug report would certainly shed more insight here.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe i didn't understand your question correctly, but you can't connect to wireless networks while your interface is in monitor mode.

Now if this wasn't the question then i'll point out a few more things to make it work as expected:

Before running *airodump-ng* you should also kill any netowrking processes determined by

```
sudo airmon-ng check
```

Now if you want to end whatever you were doing, you stop the monitor mode

```
sudo airmon-ng stop mon0
```

And start netowrking services

```
sudo service networking start
sudo service network-manager start
```

Comment: You're wrong, I *can* run airodump-ng on the mon0 interface while still browsing the web through wlp3s0. I know that there are wifi cards which don't support this, but mine allows it. Also, why do you think killing the other network processes would keep airodump-ng from crashing my session if the wifi gets disabled?

Comment: I don't quite understand what's with disabling wifi, but _airmon-ng_ isn't meant to run along with networking services, when you start the monitor mode it even gives you warning about processes that might cause conflicts

Comment: Yes, there is this warning and for some cards, it might cause problems if other processes still use it, but mine is totally fine with capturing packets in monitor mode while still surfing the web etc. I can try and kill those processes first and see what happens if I disable the Wifi then, but I don't expect a change.

Comment: Please see my updated question. My session does not crash if I disable the WiFi using `sudo ifconfig wlp3s0 down`, no matter whether I killed other processes like NetworkManager before or not. So might it even be a bug in the NetworkManager instead of airodump-ng?

Comment: Please help me to understand why do you need to disable wlp3s0 while running it in monitor mode

Comment: I had airodump-ng running in background while surfing on the web. The signal strength of my own WiFi AP is pretty bad in my room, so the connection often breaks and it's sometimes unable to reconnect it again. I thought quickly disabling my WiFi and enabling it again could help it finding the AP again faster. So I opened the network indicator menu and clicked on "Enable WiFi" to uncheck it. That's when my session crashed. This crashing is reproducible using the network indicator, but not using `sudo ifconfig wlp3s0 down`.

Comment: The crashing pobably has to do something with conflicting processes while running interface in monitor mode. On aircrack-ng official page it is even written: _"<check|check kill> “check” will show any processes that might interfere with the aircrack-ng suite. It is strongly recommended that these processes be eliminated prior to using the aircrack-ng suite. “check kill” will check and kill off processes that might interfere with the aircrack-ng suite."_. So as your scenario isn't officially supported you are pretty much alone in this situation.

Comment: I would like to try it again with the processes killed, but I can't find a command-line method to disable the WiFi other than `sudo ifconfig wlp3s0 down`, but this one does not crash. Do you know what the indicator is doing behind the scenes?

Comment: In that case i think `sudo ifconfig wlp3s0 down` and `sudo ifconfig wlp3s0 up` is correct way of disabling/enabling wifi. And if it doesn't break the airodump-ng session then feel free to use this method